# ghostscript extract pages containing a text string

Tags: pdf, ghostscript, aix

i need to programmatically extract from a multipage pdf, only the pages containing a text string. Is it possible or i need some other tools? I'm working on aix.

thanx in advance

Answer (score 0):

OK firstly Ghostscript doesn't extract pages from PDF files. It creates brand new PDF files whose visual appearance should be the same as the original, but whose content will be different.

There is no way to do this with Ghostscript in a single pass. You could use the txtwrite device to extract the text then grep through the output files for the text you want, note the page numbers and then run another pass to get those pages into new files.

Be aware that extracting text from a PDF file is far from guaranteed to work! That was not the intent of the original PDF format.

Also note that GHostscript currently only allows for handling a single range of pages, First->Last, so if you have a discontinuous set (eg pages 1, 3, 5, 7 etc) then you will have to run this step multiple times.